# Is it ok to take a Skype Interview as "just experience"?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I had a Skype interview scheduled after I applied for an internship offer. However in the meantime, I received an internship offer, one of a kind I cannot refuse, and I wasn't much into the first offer anyway.
As the company that proposed the second internship offer is a sponsor of my school, and is looking for numerous interns, and I currently am the first and only to apply, I am pretty sure to get the internship.

As english i not my native language, is it ok to use the Skype interview as "experience" to gain confidence, or is it unfair to the first company, who will spend some time interviewing someone who will not accept their its offer anyway ?

Comment: Do you actually have a formal offer in writing from the second company? If not, **then you don't have an offer yet**, whatever you might think your chances are.

Comment: As a point to ponder: the question doesn't specify whether the internships are paid, but if not, the job itself would be real work for "just experience," which is considered an acceptable trade in the circles that don't pay interns.

Answer (score 2):

Once you accept a written offer, you should no longer conduct interviews with other employers.

If you have not accepted a written offer, you are free to interview with whom you want in good conscience.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP already had the other interview scheduled and in the meantime accepted a different offer. Does your answer mean that he should cancel the scheduled interview?